# Encrypt Data MongoDB Kmip

Tags: mongodb, kmip

I'm trying to encrypt the data of my MongoDB database (very sensitive data). MongoDB Entreprise advises to use a KMIP server.

What do you advise me to use to manage my keys compatible with the KMIP protocol? I find that installing my own server can be complicated to maintain.

That's why I would be more reassured to go through a company that offers a KMS. AWS or Google offers this kind of service but are not compatible with the KMIP protocol.

What do you advise me?
Thank you

Comment: Link to documentation you are attempting to follow.

Comment: @D.SM https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/

Comment: Atlas does this. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-kms-encryption/

Comment: @D.SM I can't use Atlas. Atlas is something that offers a full service in the cloud. I'm just looking for a KMS (with kmip protocol)